# Firefox absolute positioning failure

Tags: html, css, firefox, absolute

My website
http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/
has a couple of issues that are only present in Firefox.

When an image on the home page is clicked on, the arrows that appear on either side to allow the user to change the picture are way at the top of the page. The div that holds the arrows should have a height of 100%, I even added `!important` to the CSS. Only Firefox doesn't show this correctly.

My css (http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/css/main.css):

```css
#sheet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display: table;
    z-index: 150;
}
#popover {
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#popover-image {
    height: 70%;
    border: 10px solid white;
}
#exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 300;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#next-image, #previous-image { cursor: pointer; background:  transparent; }
#next-image::-moz-selection, #previous-image::-moz-selection,
#next-image::selection, #previous-image::selection { background: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
#leftArrow, #rightArrow {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    display: table;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
}
#leftArrow { left: 0; } #rightArrow { right: 0; }
#next-image {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -moz-text-stroke: 1px black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
}
#previous-image {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -moz-text-stroke: 1px black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

My HTML (http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/default.php):

```
<div id="sheet">
    <div id="exit">Exit</div>

    <div id="popover">
        <div id="leftArrow"><div id="previous-image" onclick="previous()">&laquo;</div></div>

        <img src="watermark.php?src=images/main1.jpg&x=0&y=420&opactity=50" id="popover-image" onclick="close()" />

        <div id="rightArrow"><div id="next-image" onclick="next()">&raquo;</div></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Every other browser that I've tried (except IE; I am on a Mac) displays the page correctly.

**EDIT: I am having more Firefox issues.**

The page at http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/photography.php shows many pictures that are in `<td>` tags and after the `img` but before the `</td>` there is a span that has an absolute position, `top: 10px;` On every browser (even IE8!!) it doesn't work correctly.

My HTML page:

```
<table id="photos">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/garden.jpg" /><span>Gardens</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/trees.jpg" /><span>Trees</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/shrubs.jpg" /><span>Shrubs</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/perennials.jpg" /><span>Perennials</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/annuals.jpg" /><span>Annuals</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/tropicals.jpg" /><span>Tropicals</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/bulb.jpg" /><span>Bulbs</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/containers.jpg" /><span>Containers</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/fruit.jpg" /><span>Fruit</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/animals.jpg" /><span>Creatures</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/people.jpg" /><span>People</span></td><td><img src="images/photo-thumbs/travel.jpg" /><span>Travel</span></td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

```css
#photos td {
        width: 192px;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    #photos td img { width: 100%; border: 1px solid gold; }
    #photos td span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        color: #f0f0f0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Almost certain it's due to your use of `display: table` - I've ran into a lot of issues with that in the past with some browsers requiring another wrapper element with `display: table-row` outside of `display: table-cell`. Why not use `position: absolute; top: 45%; right: 30px` or something like that instead of hacking a table-like layout? You could also do `top: 50%; margin-top: -[arrowHeight/2];` to get the arrow precisely in the middle.

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked very well.

Comment: @afterimagedesign please have look on my answer and let me know if any issues or i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer of your second part: Hover issue with span position. It is working fine see the below changes i have done in html, css and jquery code. please let me know if i am missing something.

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/brNdq/1/

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/brNdq/1/embedded/result/

**HTML:**

```
<table id="photos">
      <tr>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/garden.jpg" /><span>Gardens</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/trees.jpg" /><span>Trees</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/shrubs.jpg" /><span>Shrubs</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/perennials.jpg" /><span>Perennials</span></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/annuals.jpg" /><span>Annuals</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/tropicals.jpg" /><span>Tropicals</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/bulb.jpg" /><span>Bulbs</span></div></td>
        <td><div class="img_container"><img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/images/photo-thumbs/containers.jpg" /><span>Containers</span></div></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img_container {
    position:relative;
}
```

**Jquery:** Remove hover from TD and put it on class .img_container

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".img_container").hover(function() {
        $(this).children('span').fadeIn('medium');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('span').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am so very sorry! I was on my phone, and I accidentally gave the +50 reputation to the wrong answer. Your answer was perfect, and I would give you double for that! I don't know how to give them, though. If I can in any way, I would like to. Again, I am sorry.

Comment: @afterimagedesign you can contact to moderator regarding that they can make the changes. My bad luck -:(

Answer (score 1):

Usign percentage for height is going to hell. From some historical reason, 100% height was taken as height of window, not display area. Avoid to use percentage - only for exception like here for width:20%.

If you want to setup height:100%, use JavaScript for that. Get height of the display area and set it up for these two divs. I'm posting an example, where I'm using it for overlay window (working also when resizing):

```
var updateInterval;

function showOverlay() {
  updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var h = 0;
    var s = 0;

    if (window.innerHeight) {
        h = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }

    if (document.body.scrollTop) {
        s = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    else if (window.pageYOffset) {
        s = window.pageYOffset;
    }

    document.getElementById('overlay').style.height   = '' + h + 'px';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.top = '' + s + 'px';
  }, 10);

  toogleHidden('overlay');
}
```

Replace overlay id for your IDs, toogleHidden is my function to display/hide the element.

You can use similar function to correctly place the element - you know e.g. that your elemtn is 32px heigh, so you will get height, divide by 2 and substract 16:

```
var top = (h / 2) - 16;
```

Than you don't need to setup height for 100% (except of whole column should be clickable).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `style="display:block"` in conjunction with `"position:absolute"` in FF